# What are Vertex Arrays in OpenGL & WebGL2?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, webgl2

I've been working with WebGL1 for some time but now that I'm learning more about WebGL2, I'm confused what `Vertex Array`s actually do. For example, in the following [example](https://github.com/WebGLSamples/WebGL2Samples/blob/master/samples/draw_primitive_restart.html#L90), I can remove all references to them (e.g. creation, binding, deletion) and the example continues to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been explained elsewhere but you can consider both WebGL1 and WebGL2 to have a vertex array. It's just WebGL1 by default only has one where as WebGL2 you can create multiple vertex arrays (although 99.9% of all WebGL1 implementations support them as an extension)

A Vertex Array is the collection of all attribute state plus the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding.

You can think of WebGL state like this

```js
class WebGLRenderingContext {
  constructor() {
   // internal WebGL state
   this.lastError: gl.NONE,
   this.arrayBuffer = null;
   this.vertexArray = {
     elementArrayBuffer: null,
     attributes: [
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, value: [0, 0, 0, 1], buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, value: [0, 0, 0, 1], buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, value: [0, 0, 0, 1], buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, value: [0, 0, 0, 1], buffer: null },
       { enabled: false, type: gl.FLOAT, size: 3, normalized: false, 
         stride: 0, offset: 0, value: [0, 0, 0, 1], buffer: null },
       ...
     ],
   }
   ...
```

And you can think of `gl.bindBuffer` as implemented like this

```js
   // Implementation of gl.bindBuffer. 
   // note this function is doing nothing but setting 2 internal variables.
   this.bindBuffer = function(bindPoint, buffer) {
     switch(bindPoint) {
       case gl.ARRAY_BUFFER;
         this.arrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
       case gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER;
         this.vertexArray.elementArrayBuffer = buffer;
         break;
       default:
         this.lastError = gl.INVALID_ENUM;
         break;
     }
   };
```

So you can see above, calling `gl.bindBuffer` with `gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` sets the `elementArray` part of the current `vertexArray`

You can also see `vertexArray` has a number of attributes. They define how to pull data out of the buffers to supply to your vertex shader. Calling `gl.getAttribLocation(someProgram, "nameOfAttribute")` tells you which attribute the vertex shader will look at to get data out of a buffer.

There's 4 functions that you use to configure how an attribute will get data from a buffer. `gl.enableVertexAttribArray`, `gl.disableVertexAttribArray`, `gl.vertexAttribPointer`, and `gl.vertexAttrib??`.

They're effectively implemented something like this

```js
this.enableVertexAttribArray = function(location) {
  const attribute = this.vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.enabled = true;  // true means get data from attribute.buffer 
};

this.disableVertexAttribArray = function(location) {
  const attribute = this.vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.enabled = false; // false means get data from attribute.value
};

this.vertexAttribPointer = function(location, size, type, normalized, stride, offset) {
  const attribute = this.vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.size       = size;       // num values to pull from buffer per vertex shader iteration
  attribute.type       = type;       // type of values to pull from buffer
  attribute.normalized = normalized; // whether or not to normalize
  attribute.stride     = stride;     // number of bytes to advance for each iteration of the vertex shader. 0 = compute from type, size
  attribute.offset     = offset;     // where to start in buffer.

  // IMPORTANT!!! Associates whatever buffer is currently *bound* to 
  // "arrayBuffer" to this attribute
  attribute.buffer     = this.arrayBuffer;
};

this.vertexAttrib4f = function(location, x, y, z, w) {
  const attribute = this.vertexArray.attributes[location];
  attribute.value[0] = x;
  attribute.value[1] = y;
  attribute.value[2] = z;
  attribute.value[3] = w;
};
```

Now, when you call `gl.drawArrays` or `gl.drawElements` the system knows how you want to pull data out of the buffers you made to supply your vertex shader. [See here for how that works](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html).

There's then 3 functions that will manage all state connected to `this.vertexArray`. They are `gl.createVertexArray`, `gl.bindVertexArray` and `gl.deleteVertexArray`. In WebGL1 they are available on the  [`OES_vertex_array_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_vertex_array_object/) extension slightly renamed. On WebGL2 they are just available by default
which is also a feature of WebGL 2.0.

Calling `gl.createVertexArray` makes new vertex array. Calling `gl.bindVertexArray` sets `this.vertexArray` to point to the one you pass in. You can imagine it implemented like this

```js
 this.bindVertexArray = function(vao) {
   this.vertexArray = vao ? vao : defaultVertexArray;
 }
```

The benefit should be obvious. Before each thing you want to draw you need to set all the attributes. Setting each attribute requires a minimum of one call per used attribute. More commonly 3 calls per attribute. One call to `gl.bindBuffer` to bind a buffer to `ARRAY_BUFFER` and one call to `gl.vertexAttribPointer` to then bind that buffer to a specific attribute and set how to pull data out and one call to `gl.enableVertexAttribArray` to turn on getting data from a buffer for the attribute.

For a typical model with positions, normals, and texture coordinates that's 9 calls, +1 more if you're using indices and need to bind a buffer to `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

With vertex arrays all those calls happen at init time. You make a vertex array for each thing you want to draw then setup the attributes for that thing. At draw time it then only takes one call to `gl.bindVertexArray` to setup all the attributes and the `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

If you'd like to just always use vertex arrays you can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/greggman/oes-vertex-array-object-polyfill) in WebGL1. It uses the built in one if the extension exists or else emulates it. Of course emulation is slower but any GPU that would need the emulation is probably already too slow.

note if you're looking for samples maybe compare the corresponding examples on https://webglfundamentals.org to https://webgl2fundamentals.org. The WebGL2 site uses vertex arrays everywhere. You'll notice in the WebGL1 examples just before drawing, for each piece of vertex data the buffer for that data is bound and then the attribute for that data is setup. In the WebGL2 examples that happens at init time instead of draw time. At draw time all that happens is calling `gl.bindVertexArray`

One extra thing about vertex arrays to be aware of is that they generally require more organization. If you're going to draw the same object more than once with different shader programs then it's possible one shader program will use different attributes for the same data. In other words, with no extra organization shaderprogram1 might use attribute 3 for position where as shaderprogram2 might attribute 2 for position. In that case the same vertex array would not work with both programs for the same data.

The solution is to manually assign the locations. You can do this in the shaders themselves in WebGL2. You can also do it by calling `gl.bindAttribLocation` before linking the shaders for each shaderprogram in both WebGL1 and WebGL2. I tend to think using `gl.bindAttribLocation` is better than doing it in GLSL because it's more [D.R.Y.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Are there other resources that explain these concepts as well as you did? Explaining the low level functionality, especially in terms of JS, is extremely useful.

Comment: Here is a [webgl state diagram](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) and a [webgl2 state diagram](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html)

Comment: this.enableVertexAttribArray put attribute.enabled=true. this.vertexAttribPointer put other attribute value, (attribute.size, .type, ...) but attribute.enabled. Why ?

Comment: because whoever designed the API made it that way. It make some sense though. enabled = false means the vertex attribute gets its value from attribute.value (set with `gl.vertexAttrib(1-4)f`). enabled = true means the vertex attribute gets its values from a buffer specified with `gl.vertexAttribPointer`.

Comment: ok i understand now!!  in the examples of your WebGL State diagram there is no disableVertexAttribArray. ;) :) https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique??? https://i.imgur.com/wOvrKnK.png

Comment: @gman , is it possible to edit (change) the code of the examples in your webgl_state_diagram ?

Comment: You should probably ask this on github. The short answer is you can download the source and try. JS has no way to step through lines of code so it just works by splitting by semicolon. (vs adding an entire javascript parser). Further there is no way to keep a stack so it can't step through functions or loops (unless again you parsed the js yourself and maybe emitted generator versions of the code). You could try to turn it into a devtools extension but I have not and besides it doesn't handle 100% of state.

Comment: I did not understand well (my English is not good enough). This is the source? : https://github.com/gfxfundamentals/webgl-fundamentals/blob/master/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html

Comment: Yes, that's the source

Comment: have you the pseudo-code for gl.framebufferTexture2D ?

Comment: You can imagine the pseudo code if you look at the state diagram and pick [an example that uses a framebuffer](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html?exampleId=draw-cube-on-cube#no-help) but basically `framebufferTexture2D(target, attachment, textureTarget, texture, level) { fb = context[target]; fb.attacments[attachment] = {texture, textureTarget, level}; )`

Comment: in the state diagram where is the "context" array ?

Comment: `context` in the pseudo code above isn't an array, it's an object of all global state. You'd normally call `bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, someFramebuffer)` which could be implemented as `bindFramebuffer(target, framebuffer) { context[target] = fb; }`. It would show up in the diagram in global state under `FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING`

Comment: is that correct ? : class WebGLRenderingContext {
      constructor() {
         ....
         this.framebufferBinding = null; 
         .....

      }
      ....
      this.bindFramebuffer(target, framebuffer) {
        framebuffer = framebuffer || defaultFramebufferForCanvas; // if null use canvas
          switch (target) {
              case: gl.FRAMEBUFFER:
                  this.framebufferBinding = framebuffer;
                  break;
              default:
              ... error ...
          }
      }
  
}

Comment: @gman, in my local webgl_state_diagram,I did not succeed in implanting requestAnimationFrame (and any other function : const f=function() {...} ). Why ?