# Why is that gl.drawElements needs rebind while gl.drawArrays doesn't?

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

Hi guys I been studying webgl these days.

There are two snippets that accomplish the same thing - draw a square. One is using gl.drawArrays for 6 vertices and one is using gl.drawElements for 4 vertices.

However I noticed that when using gl.drawArrays, we can unbind gl.ARRAY_BUFFER before using it, it doesn't matter. See the snippets.

```
function initBuffers() {
      /*
        V0                    V3
        (-0.5, 0.5, 0)        (0.5, 0.5, 0)
        X---------------------X
        |                     |
        |                     |
        |       (0, 0)        |
        |                     |
        |                     |
        X---------------------X
        V1                    V2
        (-0.5, -0.5, 0)       (0.5, -0.5, 0)
      */
      const vertices = [
        // first triangle (V0, V1, V2)
        -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0,

        // second triangle (V0, V2, V3)
        -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0
      ];

      // Setting up the VBO
      squareVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
      // Clean
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    }

function draw() {
      // Clear the scene
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

      // Clean
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    }
```

`initBuffers()` is called before `draw()`. Notice here I already unbind `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` before calling `gl.drawArrays` and it successfully draws the square.

However when using gl.drawElements, I have to make sure `gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` is currently binded to the correct indices. e.g.

```
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareIndexBuffer);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

if I use `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);` like I did for `gl.drawArrays`, I have to rebind it using `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareIndexBuffer);` before calling `gl.drawElements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164577/128511

The short version is `gl.drawArrays` uses only attributes. Attributes have buffers bound to them when you call `gl.vertexAttribPointer`. Whatever buffer was bound do `gl.ARRAY_BUFFER` at the time you call `gl.verexAttribPointer` is copied into the state of that attribute.

Attributes themselves are state of the current Vertex Array Object (VAO) as is the current ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. VAOs are an optional extension in WebGL1 and a standard part of WebGL2.

Again refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27164577/128511 and also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50257695/128511

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am not exactly sure what you meant by `Whatever buffer was bound do gl.ARRAY_BUFFER at the time you call gl.verexAttribPointer is copied into the state of that attribute.` However I looked at those links you put out and I felt like I am getting the hang of it. Correct me if I am wrong. The reason `gl.drawArrays` doesn't need rebind is because `gl.vertexAttribPointer` has internally stored the arrayBuffer so that we can just use. On the other hand `gl.drawElements` has the global elementArrayBuffer, so we have to rebind it if we unbinded it before.

Comment: Correct for `gl.drawArrays`.  For `gl.drawElements` the elementArrayBuffer is part of the current `vertexArray` state. In WebGL1 there is only one global vertexArray unless you enable the `OES_vertex_array` extension. In WebGL2 there are as many vertexArrays as you create (see `gl.createVertexArray`, `gl.bindVertexArray`). A vertex array contains all of the attribute state **and** the elementArrayBuffer state

Comment: thanks for your reply! Since we can have multiple VAOs in webgl2 to store attribute state and the elementArrayBuffer state, do we need to distinguish which VAO stores which attribute state and which elementArrayBuffer state? Is there a way to check?