# Do we need rebind IBO after binding VAO during drawing?

Tags: graphics, webgl, webgl2

Hi I been studying webgl.

I been reading this book called `Real-Time 3D Graphics with WebGL 2` and here it says this Vertex array objects allows us to store all of the vertex/index binding information for a set of buffers in a single, easy to manage object.

And it provides this example for VAO.

```
 function initBuffers() {
      /*
        V0                    V3
        (-0.5, 0.5, 0)        (0.5, 0.5, 0)
        X---------------------X
        |                     |
        |                     |
        |       (0, 0)        |
        |                     |
        |                     |
        X---------------------X
        V1                    V2
        (-0.5, -0.5, 0)       (0.5, -0.5, 0)
      */
      const vertices = [
        -0.5, 0.5, 0,
        -0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, -0.5, 0,
        0.5, 0.5, 0
      ];

      // Indices defined in counter-clockwise order
      indices = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3];

      // Create VAO instance
      squareVAO = gl.createVertexArray();

      // Bind it so we can work on it
      gl.bindVertexArray(squareVAO);

      const squareVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      // Provide instructions for VAO to use data later in draw
      gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.aVertexPosition);
      gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

      // Setting up the IBO
      squareIndexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareIndexBuffer);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

      // Clean
      gl.bindVertexArray(null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    }

    // We call draw to render to our canvas
    function draw() {
      // Clear the scene
      gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

      // Bind the VAO
      gl.bindVertexArray(squareVAO);

      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, squareIndexBuffer);

      // Draw to the scene using triangle primitives
      gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

      // Clean
      gl.bindVertexArray(null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    }

    // Entry point to our application
    function init() {
      // Retrieve the canvas
      const canvas = utils.getCanvas('webgl-canvas');

      // Set the canvas to the size of the screen
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

      // Retrieve a WebGL context
      gl = utils.getGLContext(canvas);
      // Set the clear color to be black
      gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

      // Call the functions in an appropriate order
      initProgram();
      initBuffers();
      draw();
    }
```

The question here is, do we need `gl.bindBuffer();` after we bind the VAO in `draw()`?

I looked at this link [What are Vertex Arrays in OpenGL & WebGL2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255115/what-are-vertex-arrays-in-opengl-webgl2/50257695#50257695) and it says 
`At draw time it then only takes one call to gl.bindVertexArray to setup all the attributes and the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. So I suppose there is no need for the  `gl.bindBuffer();` after we bind the VAO in `draw()`? 
Is the code from the textbook misleading?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to rebind the buffer

The ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding is part of the current vertex array state as the answer you linked to points out.

These lines in your example are also irrelevant

In `initBuffers`

```
  // Clean
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

None of these lines are truly needed. Only the first line has any real point even if it is not needed

This line

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

does nothing really because as stated above `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` state is part of the current vertex array so just changing the current vertex array with `gl.bindVertexArray` already changed that binding.

This line

```
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_BUFFER, null);
```

has no point really because AFAIK almost no programs ever just assume the current ARRAY_BUFFER binding is set to anything. They always bind a buffer before operating on it. It's not bad to have it and I'm sure you could find some convoluted way to make it important but in real life I haven't seen one.

This line does have a point.

```
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
```

It is common to setup vertex buffers separate from vertex attributes. If you are making one vertex array per thing to draw and your pattern is like this

```
  // at init time
  for each thing I plan to draw
    (1) create buffers and fill with positions/normals/texcoords/indices
    (2) create/bind vertex array
    (3) setup attributes and ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
```

Then if you don't bind `null` after step 3, step 1 will end up changing the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER binding of the previously bound vertex array

In other words maybe this line

```
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
```

Has a point. Still, it's arguable. If you swapped steps 1 and 2 and changed your initialization to

```
  // at init time
  for each thing I plan to draw
    (1) create/bind vertex array
    (2) create buffers and fill with positions/normals/texcoords/indices
    (3) setup attributes
```

Then the problem goes away

Those same 3 lines exist in `draw`

```
  // Clean
  gl.bindVertexArray(null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

Where again they have no point

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply! really informative. Still have one question I'd like to ask: when you said "It is common to setup vertex buffers separate from vertex attributes. If you are making one vertex array per thing to draw and your pattern is like this..." the pattern below contains `(1) create buffers and fill with positions/normals/texcoords/indices` and ` (3) setup attributes and ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. I am not sure I understand this. First step has  `indices`, so you fill in the `gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` using `indices` right? how come the third step also includes `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`

Comment: Also why is that when we swap steps 1 and 2, the problems goes away i.e. it is fine if we don't bind `gl.bindVertexArray(null);`. Is it because we create a new VAO for every ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER therefore  bind `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` changing the binding of the previously bound vertex array?

Comment: The 3rd step contains the element array buffer because if you haven't bound the VAO when you created the indices which you didn't since create indices is step 1 and create VAO is step 2 then your ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER would be bound to the either the previous VAO or the default VAO, whichever was bound when you created the indices. Swapping the order means your new VAO is bound first so when you create your indices they get bound to your new VAO. Look at the link you posted in your question. It shows how these functions work. Look at how ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER works. It should be clear why